# MongoDB Aggregation - How to get/update sum

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

For example, I have something in my database like in customers collection.

```
{
  Max: {
    shoping_list: { 
      food: { Pizza: 2, Ramen: 1, Sushi: 5 }
    }
  },
  John: {
    shoping_list: { 
      food: { Pizza: 2, Ramen: 1, Burger: 1 }
    }
  }
}
```

In my backend, I want to get the sum of food

```js
const request = await customers.aggregate([
   {
     $group: {
       _id: null,
       Pizza: {
         $sum: '$shoping_list.food.Pizza',
   },
```

Is there a way how to update or get the sum automatically without manually writing every food from the `shopping_list`?

Comment: The `Max` and `John` are the properties in the document?

Comment: @YongShun Yes, sorry for the unclear message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design of the document may lead the query looks complex but still achievable.

1. `$replaceRoot` - Replace the input document with a new document.

   1.1. `$reduce` - Iterate the array and transform it into a new form (array).

   1.2. `input` - Transform key-value pair of current document `$$ROOT` to an array of objects such as: `[{ k: "", v: "" }]`

   1.3. `initialValue` - Initialize the value with an empty array. And this will result in the output in the array.

   1.4. `in`

   1.4.1. `$concatArrays` - Combine aggregate array result (`$$value`) with *1.4.2*.

   1.4.2. With the `$cond` operator to filter out the document with `{ k: "_id" }`, and we transform the current iterate object's `v` `shoping_list.food` to the array via `$objectToArray`.
2. `$unwind` - Deconstruct the `foods` array into multiple documents.
3. `$group` - Group by `foods.k` and perform sum for `foods.v`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        foods: {
          $reduce: {
            input: {
              $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"
            },
            initialValue: [],
            in: {
              $concatArrays: [
                "$$value",
                {
                  $cond: {
                    if: {
                      $ne: [
                        "$$this.k",
                        "_id"
                      ]
                    },
                    then: {
                      $objectToArray: "$$this.v.shoping_list.food"
                    },
                    else: []
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$foods"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$foods.k",
      sum: {
        $sum: "$foods.v"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DtTHcBs8cTo)

Comment: What if I want the result to look like this 
{  
   Burger: 1,
   Ramen: 2,
   Pizza: 4,
   Sushi: 5,
}

Comment: You need a `$group` stage to group all documents to one. And `$replaceWith` to show document as key-value pair. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wIq5o7ywkug).